# How to make mysql like and not like fetch strings from a list

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following mysql code

```
SELECT * FROM loans_book WHERE the_amount < 500000 
AND 
loan_amount_you_require 
NOT LIKE '%avensis%' 
OR 
loan_amount_you_require  
NOT LIKE '%prius%'
OR
loan_amount_you_require 
NOT LIKE '%porsch%'
OR
```

the problem is,if i keep adding the not likes,they are bound to add up to 100 and i suspect the list could grow longer.

I like the way mysql has `NOT IN` where i can comma separate my strings but `not like` is different in that i need to specify the column name each time.

is there a way i could possibly go around the requirement to state the column name each time i want to use `not like`?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using `NOT REGEXP` for this... Query should look like the following:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    loans_book
WHERE
    the_amount < 500000 
    AND loan_amount_you_require NOT REGEXP 'avensis|prius|porsch';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
   * 
FROM
   loans_book
WHERE 
   the_amount < 500000 
   AND 
   loan_amount_you_require NOT REGEXP ('avensis|prius|porsch')
```

Comment: This only works if the field is exactly `avensis`, `prius` or `porsch`... And that is not what OP wants...

Comment: I'm just getting some new idea and try it with my own. I am also a learner.

Answer (score -1):

Checking against a pattern list in a regular expression should do the trick:

```
 SELECT * 
   FROM loans_book    
  WHERE the_amount < 500000 
    AND loan_amount_you_require 
 REGEXP '(avensis|prius|porsch)';
```

See also http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/regexp.html